# How to authenticate in the Wigle API for get requests

Tags: json, get

I'm trying to query the Wigle API from a jupyter notebook with the code below, but keep receiving the following error:

HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?onlymine=false&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssidlike=Marriott

I suspect it has something to do with authentication, but in the documentation page on Wigle, I don't see/understand where I would include my api key. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The below code is what I tried:

```
import requests
import json
```

```
ssidlike = "Marriott"
url = f"https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?onlymine=false&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssidlike={ssidlike}"
```

```
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()  

if response.status_code != 204:
    return response.json()
```

I expected to receive a JSON return of the above query, but what resulted was the following error:

**HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.wigle.net/api/v2/network/search?onlymine=false&freenet=false&paynet=false&ssidlike=Marriott**

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your WiGLE.net account credentials (the API name and Token available at https://wigle.net/account) in order to authenticate the request - then use python requests basic auth:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=('<API Name from above>','<API Token from above>'))
```